# Is there a way to add a complex flutter app with flutter_storyBook as a module for a native Kotlin App?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, native, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a very complex flutter app with story book and everything, and I'd like to reuse the code inside my native Kotlin app, but it's a lot of screens, login and everything, and it has flutter_storybook

I've tried following the flutter docs tutorial for integrating as a module (considering just my main.dart as entry point), but I ended stuck with a black screen everytime I try to launch de FlutterActivity, is there anything more I need to do????

Comment: What I'm trying to do is basically use the whole flutter application inside this native app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.